# Determine if AlarmManager already started between app restart

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I set a timer with AlarmManager on boot and the delay between calls is pretty big. Enough for my whole app to get killed between calls (even the singletons are recreated when the timer fires).

I want to make sure the timer is stared either on boot or when the user first start the app. Since there is no way for me to store a variable somewhere since my app gets totally unloaded from memory between timer calls, how can I tell if the timer is already running?

Thank you.

Comment: Save a flag in SharedPreferences? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: could you please reframe your question with some code and a clearer explanation of what you are trying to achieve ?